# How to delete a commit from Github's history that is not present locally?

Tags: git, github, version-control

I pushed a commit to Github with some private information. I've created a new branch that no longer has that information, and I've deleted the old branch, so the commit doesn't show up in the history of the branches.

However, you can still access a Github page showing the old commit using a URL in this format: `https://github.com/me/myrepo/commit/4d929e07c2a61f261950f37af8d6fe5ec5ed05e1#diff-84e94b10bf89d08c7eb37dc4887fc612fb3115ff806e2661eb9e07c2a6186ebeR1`. The commit in question does not show up if you run `git log`.

How can I get rid of it?

Comment: Did you delete the branch on Github as well?

Comment: I did, yes. When I go to the link in question, it shows this message: "This commit does not belong to any branch on this repository, and may belong to a fork outside of the repository."

Comment: If you owned the repo, you would need to run `git gc` (with some options to indicate "drop stuff *now*") to have git clean your local repo. AFAIK, you don't have a direct way to do this on a repo hosted on github, you need to contact github's tech support to ask them to make it happen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GitHub has extensive documentation about this. They have a documentation page for this called [Removing sensitive data from a repository](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository#purging-a-file-from-your-repositorys-history) that I would recommend you read.

They suggest you contact [GitHub Support](https://support.github.com/contact) so they can remove the cached version of the history.

Hope that helps somewhat.